# RTC Jazz server User Login using Automation Anywhere

Tags: automationanywhere

I want to download an extract from an RTC server using Automation Anywhere. The issue i am facing is the user authentication window. As the user login window appears only once in a day (the first time login), i want a condition such as "IF the user login window appears THEN enter username and password". So i'm looking got an IF/ELSE condition in such a way the if it finds a user login window, it is able to authenticate the user and let him/her login, but if not, then it should continue with rest of the code (the download one).
Please feel free to ask questions if my query wasn't explanatory.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This if condition should work with your problem

[image]

Comment: It worked... :) Thanks so much for helping on the solution Jonx.
Just a small doubt, the app will continue the next step outside the 'IF/ELSE' if the 'Authentication Window' doesn't appear right ?

Comment: Mark as solved for the next one. Yes, this will wait 5 second for the window then continue